# Twitter: How to get "View photo" on tweet

Tags: twitter, facebook-opengraph

We just included a pure HTML link for the tweet functionality instead of the twitter button. Now we want to enable the user to tweet an image together with his tweet.

When you manually tweet an url from instagram or flickrm, twitter automatically adds the "View photo" function below the tweet? How did I get that on my page?

I already found out, that both instagram and flickr use og properties. My guess was, that I have to add those properties to my page. But even adding those properties does not trigger the "View photo" link on twitter.

Is there some documentation about how to get it working? I didn't found anything in the API docs.

Comment: OK, I just found out that even pinterest has those og properties, but when you tweet a pinterest URL, there is no "View photo" link either. So it might be the case, that twitter only supports some whitelisted pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `View Photo` link on Twitter is not related to OpenGraph. The photo provides are approved by Twitter so it automatically adds the `View Photo` link to tweets that include one of those services. If you want the View Photo link in your tweets, consider uploading photos using the TwitPic API or similar.

Comment: OK thanks for that imformation. Although it might not help to upload pictures to third party services, as we wanted to enable our users to instantly tweet a page and have the image added automatically.